# How to have a field in my form whitout displaying it in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I

I use a collection field to display twice all the text of a project that I'm creating (one collection for french, the other for english), but I choose to not display the field langague because the user is not suppose to be able to change that. To do this, I wrote:

```
{% for description in form.descriptions %}
            {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                French
            {% elseif loop.index == 2 %}
                English
            {% endif %}
            <li>
                {% do description.language.setRendered %}   
                ...
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

The thing is that I first tried writting my controller like this:

```
public function ajoutAction(Request $request)
  {
    //Crée un nouveau projet
    $nouveauProjet = new Projet();

    //Crée les descriptions
    $descriptionFr = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionEn = new ProjetInt();

    //Indique le bon code de langue pour les descriptions
    $descriptionFr->setLangue('fr');
    $descriptionEn->setLangue('en');

    //Associe le projet et les descriptions
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionFr);
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionEn);
    $descriptionFr->setProjet($nouveauProjet);
    $descriptionEn->setProjet($nouveauProjet);

    //Formulaires pour la création d'un projet
    $formulaire=$this->createForm(new ProjetType(), $nouveauProjet);

    //On surveille le formulaire
    $formulaire->handleRequest($request);

    //Si le formulaire est valide
    if($formulaire->isValid())
    {
      ...
    }

    return $this->render('AdminBundle::ajoutProjet.html.twig',array(
                                      'formulaire'=>$formulaire->createView()
                                    ));
  }
```

The problem is that when I submit the form, it doesn't find the language because of what I did inside my template, so insted, my controller looks like this:

```
public function ajoutAction(Request $request)
  {
    //Crée un nouveau projet
    $nouveauProjet = new Projet();

    //Crée les descriptions
    $descriptionFr = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionEn = new ProjetInt();

    //Associe le projet et les descriptions
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionFr);
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionEn);
    $descriptionFr->setProjet($nouveauProjet);
    $descriptionEn->setProjet($nouveauProjet);

    //Formulaires pour la création d'un projet
    $formulaire=$this->createForm(new ProjetType(), $nouveauProjet);

    //On surveille le formulaire
    $formulaire->handleRequest($request);

    //Si le formulaire est valide
    if($formulaire->isValid())
    {
      //Indique le bon code de langue pour les descriptions
      $descriptionFr->setLangue('fr');
      $descriptionEn->setLangue('en');

      //Applique les modifications
      $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($nouveauProjet);
      $em->flush();

      ...
    }
  }
```

It's just a detail, but it REALLY annoys me. I really want to set my language outside of `if($formulaire->isValid())`

Comment: Why don't you make the field type hidden then? `->add('languague', 'hidden', ...)`

Comment: Why you don't set it on beginning:  `$descriptionFr->setProjet($nouveauProjet)->setLanguage('fr');`

Comment: For the first comment, if I hide it, the user could juste change my css and start screwing around with the language. For the seconde one, I can't set it in the beginning, because he won't be able the find the language if I do that because my field is setted to rendered in my twig, but it seems that doing so  makes that my form doesn't save the language field, that's why I set it after. I want to no how I could set it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a WAY BETTER way to do this. In the form, I gave the language field the attribute `'read_only'=>true`. This allowed me to change my controller to be exactly as I wanted it. I don't need to use the line `{% do description.language.setRendered %}` and I can just use what is written in the language field to display the language of the description (fr = french and en=english). The only thing that is needed is to use some CSS to hide the field language and it doesn't matter if someone tweak the CSS to display it since they can't edit the field anyway. Voilà!

Here is the code:

the form:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

Class ProjetIntType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $constructeur, array $options)
    {
        $constructeur
        ->add('langue', 'text', array('read_only'=>true))
        ->add('nom', 'text')
        ->add('descriptionCours', 'text')
        ->add('descriptionComplete', 'text')
        ->add('roles', 'text')
        ->add('aptitudesDeveloppees', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt',
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {

        return 'projetInt';

    }

}
```

The controller:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
  {
    //New project
    $nouveauProjet = new Projet();

    //New descriptions
    $descriptionFr = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionFr->setLangue('fr');
    $descriptionFr->setProjet($nouveauProjet);

    $descriptionEn = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionEn->setLangue('en');
    $descriptionEn->setProjet($nouveauProjet);

    //Add the descriptions to the project
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionFr);
    $nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionEn);

    ...
}
```

My twig:

```
{{ form_start(formulaire, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
    {#  #}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.imageFile) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.technologie) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.annee) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.type) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.fichierFile) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.largeur) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.hauteur) }}
    {{ form_row(formulaire.categories) }}
    {#  #}
    <h3>Descriptions</h3>
    <ul class="descriptions">
        {% for description in formulaire.descriptions %}
            {% if description.langue.vars.value == 'fr' %}
                Français
            {% elseif description.langue.vars.value == 'en' %}
                Anglais
            {% endif %}
            <li>    
                {{ form_row(description.langue) }}
                {{ form_row(description.nom) }}
                {{ form_row(description.descriptionCours) }}
                {{ form_row(description.descriptionComplete) }}
                {{ form_row(description.roles) }}
                {{ form_row(description.aptitudesDeveloppees) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="{{ textBtn }}"/>
{{ form_end(formulaire) }}
```